# Need xslt output for following xml

Tags: java, xml, xslt

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <ConfigurationMappings>
     <ConfigurationMap>
     <Widget Type="All" Include="true" NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
     <Trigger Type="Show" />
     <ConfigurationEffects>
     <Effect>1</Effect>
     <Effect>2</Effect>
     <Effect>3</Effect>
     <Effect>9</Effect>
     </ConfigurationEffects>
     </ConfigurationMap>
     <ConfigurationMap>
     <Widget Type="All" Include="true" NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
     <Trigger Type="Hide" />
     <ConfigurationEffects>
     <Effect>1</Effect>
     <Effect>2</Effect>
     <Effect>3</Effect>
     <Effect>9</Effect>
     </ConfigurationEffects>
     </ConfigurationMap>
     </ConfigurationMappings>
```

Need to write xsl for the above XML input.As output will be in the form for widget type all and trigger type show need to output all the effects 
Need help regarding how to write the xsl,As i am not aware of xsl. and my project require this

i wrote the below xsl from my own

```
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="ConfigurationMappings/ConfigurationMap/Widget/@Type"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="ConfigurationMappings/ConfigurationMap/Trigger/@Type"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="ConfigurationMappings/ConfigurationMap/ConfigurationEffects/Effect"/></td>
 </tr>
```

which is giving output in the below format:

```
Widget Trigger Effects
----------------------------
All     Show     1
```

But i want the output in the below format
Widget Trigger Effects

```
---------------------------
All     Show     1
--------------------------
All     Show     2
--------------------------
All     Show     3
-------------------------
All     Show     9
----------------------------
All     Hide     1
---------------------------
All     Hide     3
--------------------------
All     Hide     6
----------------------------
All     Hide     9
---------------------------------
```

Please help me guyz
Ignore the sub-headers(----) as added for posting the questions

Comment: have you done any google in it??ortry something from your own?

Comment: yes i googled for the same and also refered the w3schools for the same.But all other examples present in the site is of simple one.This is some how complex so that why need help for the same

Comment: Try to do it from your own first... we will be very much glad to answer the issues that you will face in doing this....

Comment: Please add this in your question please

Comment: @usman--add in the question what i tried to done and what im trying to achieve...if you guide or suggest then it will be great help from your side

Answer (score 1):

So you want one row for each `Effect` element containing the effect number along with the corresponding widget type and trigger type?  How about

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tr><th>Widget</th><th>Trigger</th><th>Effects</th></tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="
           ConfigurationMappings/ConfigurationMap/ConfigurationEffects/Effect" />
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Effect">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Widget/@Type"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Trigger/@Type"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will fire the second template once for *each* `Effect` element, and then we navigate from there up to the `Widget` and `Trigger` elements belonging to the same `ConfigurationMap`.